# HTML Tags not working properly in swift code

Tags: html, ios, swift, string

Here is my html string:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style>
        body {
               color: #510020;    
               font-family: -apple-system;      
               font-size: 18.0px;       
       }       
     </style>       
  </head>  
  <body>
     <b>hi. Testing this for ios</b><i>hi. Testing this for ios</i><u>hi. Testing this for ios</u>   
  </body>        
</html>
```

This is working fine in the browser. But when I am trying to render it in UI it's not rendering properly with attributed html string in swift here is swift code

```
    if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: txt.data(using: .utf8)!, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil) {
        return attributedString
    }
```

**This code returns complete text as bold string, while I want the actual output as per HTML**

Comment: If it's font and color issue then you need manage that dynamically with swift.

Comment: I tried your code in playground. The attributed string is rendering correctly all 3 styles, and it shows correctly when used in NSTextField for example. How are you setting it on UI element?

Comment: @Jay no, you don't. What he is doing is generally valid.

Comment: Did you set the `numberOfLines` to `0`? Is it possible that your string is just getting trimmed to what it can show in a single line?

Comment: You should add screen snapshot of what you're getting, but this is what I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbraE.png